# Python sqlalchemy - independent transactions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a question about transactions in flask-sqlalchemy.

```
def funca():
    instance = MyModel.query.get(5)

    try:
        instance.some_field = 'test'
        instance.do_something()
        instance.do_something_other() # Let's pretend that this causes exception
        db.session.commit()
     except Exception:
        db.session.rollback()

# My model method
def do_something(self):
    external_id = self.make_request_to_external_service()
    self.external_id = external_id

# My model method
def do_something_other(self):
    external_details = self.make_another_external_request()
    self.external_details = external_details
```

How can I achieve now, that on Exception this will rollback only `some_field` and `external_details` changes and `external_id` is still saved in db?

Can I use nested transaction or can I start manually independent transactions for these 3 operations?

Problem here is that `do_something` will get `external_id` and it must be saved in db, because I can't do it second time, also if I won't rollback this transaction `some_field` will cause desynchronization between my db and external service.

For this example's purposes let's pretend that I can't do `do_something` before `instance.some_field = 'test'`, because I could run this and commit this independently, but I can't do that in my real life app.

Comment: Put them in separate try...catch.

Comment: Whether or not you can use [nested transactions (SAVEPOINT)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.begin) depends on which DB you are using. If yes, then use that.